# Is rank of a linear operator on manifold always constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This may sound like a dumb question and I don't know whether this is a pure Linear Algebraic question or it is a valid Differential geometry question.

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold and $L_g:V \to V$ a linear operator defined on a vector bundle $V$. I want to know whether the rank of $L$ is always constant or it may vary by changing $p\in M$? is it changes by changing basis of $V$? and $L_g$ needs more assumption for being of constant rank?

**Update:**

More specifically, I want to know if the rank of curvature operator $\mathcal{R}:\Lambda^2 TM\to \Lambda^2 TM$ on a closed Riemannian manifold is constant or not.

Comment: The rank of a linear operator doesn't change when you change basis. However, the rank of $L$ might depend on $p$.  (For example, take the identity operator (globally defined) and multiply it by a smooth compactly supported scalar function).

Comment: Consider $E=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}$ and the endomorphism $f(x,t)=(x,tx)$. It doesn't have constant rank.

Comment: Well, What conditions should I check for $L$ to ensure that it has constant rank? In my work, $L_g$ is the curvature operator defined on $\Lambda^2 TM$.

Comment: It may be helpful to you to know that the set of points on which the rank is locally constant is an open and dense set. The rank is then necessarily constant on connected components of that set - this divides your manifold into different open "pieces" on which your map has constant rank.

Comment: The rank of a smooth map is not necessarily constant, even locally, but it is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: @Kajelad: Your comment is a response to s.harp comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of a curvature operator is not necessarily constant. Consider for example the complex projective line $\mathbb P^1$ with the Fubini-Study metric $g$, which is a Riemannian metric. As it's a surface, the curvature operator identifies with the scalar curvature. The Fubini-Study metric has constant curvature 2, so its curvature operator has constant rank 1.

Now consider metrics of the form $e^{cf} g$, where $f$ is smooth and $c$ is a constant. Their curvature is
$$
2 + c \Delta f,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian. So if we pick a function $f$ whose Laplacian is not identically zero, we can pick $c$ such that the curvature of the metric is $0$ at some point, and thus the rank of the curvature operator is zero there. Note that by Gauss-Bonnet the curvature operator cannot be zero everywhere, so where it is not zero it will have rank 1.